# How Django finds all the migrations

Tags: django, migration, django-south

I want to a create an Elasticsearch Index maintenance utility that is similar to how Django migrations behave - I want each Django app to have an 'elasticindices' package, and have the index definitions there.

How does Django (and previously south) scan all apps and finds the migrations?

Comment: Here's where Django loads them: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/loader.py#L59

Comment: you ought to check out http://haystacksearch.org/  it's an abstraction between search backends (including ElasticSearch) and Django and they already provide exactly this via an autodiscovered `search_indexes.py` in your project apps